# On Commensurable and Incommensurable Magnitudes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, euclidean-geometry

I'm having quite a twisted time trying to understand the definitions provided for commensurable and incommebsurable magnitudes, specifically those provided by Euclid.

Euclid defines those magnitudes that have a common measure with one another to be commensurable, and those otherwise Incommensurable. First of all, wouldn't a unit always be a common measure between any two numbers? Say, both $√2$ and $3$ are measured by a unit, yet these are considered to be incommensurable with each other. And if you limit the definition in such a way so that incommensurable magnitudes are those that don't have a common measure other than the unit, then how is this different from being co-prime?

Also, I fail to see what relation Incommensurability has to irrationality, for I've been told so they do. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Two magnitudes are *commensurable* if one is a *rational multiple* of the other. The "common measure" stuff indicates that each magnitude can be broken into certain (whole) #s of congruent pieces: eg, breaking $a$ into $n$ equal pieces and $b$ into $m$ equal pieces, such that $a/n=b/m=\text{common measure}$ ... whence, $a=b\cdot\frac{n}{m}$ and $b=a\cdot\frac{m}{n}$ (there's the "rational multiple" bit). For $\sqrt{2}$ to be commensurable with $1$, we'd need whole #s $m$ and $n$ such that $\sqrt{2}=1\cdot\frac{m}{n}$; as there are no such $m$ and $n$, $\sqrt{2}$ and $1$ are incommensurable.

Comment: Suppose you had a ruler based on some unit, w/markings at whatever rational pts you like (half-unit, double-unit, seven-nineteeths units, etc). With that ruler, you draw squares of various sizes. $1\times1$, $31\times 31$, $0.9\times0.9$, etc. Fun! But, that ruler cannot precisely measure the diagonals of those squares. So, you build a new ruler whose unit *is* one of those diagonals, with markings at whatever rational pts (*relative to that unit*) you like. With *that* ruler, you can precisely measure *all* the squares' diagonals (as they are commensurable w/$\sqrt{2}$), but not their sides.